# execute julia scripts from Java

Tags: java, julia, execute

I'm coding Julia script with ZeroMQ.

My goal is to communicate with ZMQ between two scripts. Here is an example:

```
# script1
using ZMQ
ctx = ZMQ.Context()
sockDealer = ZMQ.Socket(ctx, DEALER)
ZMQ.set_identity(sockDealer, "idA")
ZMQ.connect(sockDealer, "tcp://localhost:5555")
ZMQ.send(sockDealer, "hello world!")
ZMQ.close(sockDealer)
ZMQ.close(ctx)



#script2
using ZMQ

function pollrecv(socket::ZMQ.Socket,zmsg::Message)
  rc = -1
  while true
    rc = ccall((:zmq_msg_recv, ZMQ.zmq), Cint, (Ptr{Message}, Ptr{Void}, Cint),
                    &zmsg, socket.data, ZMQ.ZMQ_DONTWAIT)
  if rc == -1
    # Base.Libc.EAGAIN = 11
    # Problem unsolved: Failure to find Base.Libc.EAGAIN
    if !(ZMQ.zmq_errno() == 11)
      throw(ZMQ.StateError(ZMQ.jl_zmq_error_str()))
    end
    return false
    else
      ZMQ.get_events(socket) != 0 && notify(socket)
      break
    end
  end
  return true
end

ctx = ZMQ.Context()
sockRouter = ZMQ.Socket(ctx, ROUTER)
ZMQ.bind(sockRouter, "tcp://*:5555")
fini = false
while !fini
  println("listening...")
  idSock = Message()
  while pollrecv(sockRouter, idSock)
    msg = ZMQ.recv(sockRouter)
    println("msg recv: " * bytestring(msg))
    fini = true
  end
  sleep(1)
end
ZMQ.close(sockRouter)
ZMQ.close(ctx)
```

I can execute them with Julia on the command prompt. Everything goes fine. Script 2 can receive the message of Script 1.

Now, I need to execute them from Java. Meaning that I need to create a java project which is just like a controller. Here is my Java project:

```
public class Container {

    private Vector<String[]> commands;

    public Container() {
        this.commands = new Vector<String[]>();
    }

    public void addCommand(String[] strs) {
        this.commands.addElement(strs);
    }

    public void execute() {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.commands.size(); i++) {
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(this.commands.get(i));
                if(p.waitFor() != 0){
                    System.err.println("exit value = " + p.exitValue());
                }
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = null;
                while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuffer.append(line + "-");
                }
                System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}


//main
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container c = new Container();

        String[] script1 = {"/usr/bin/julia", "/home/thomas/Julia/script1.jl"};
        String[] script2 = {"/usr/bin/julia", "/home/thomas/Julia/script2.jl"};
        c.addCommand(script1);
        c.addCommand(script2);
        c.execute();
    }
}
```

However, when I run my java project, I can see that it keeps running but I can't see anything on the console: no result, no message, no error.

I think there is something wrong in my java project.

Comment: You `p.waitFor()`, which will wait for the process to terminate. So, your second script only gets executed when the first one finishes.

Comment: @Kenney   So I should remove that `if` or what? I don't quite understand how to capture the out stream of an executable file from a java project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to run the two scripts concurrently: `script2` is the server script, so it should be running when you run `script1`. As it is now, [Process.waitFor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) will wait for `script1`, the client script, to complete, before executing the server script `script2` in the next `for` iteration.

You could start them as such:

```
    String[] clientScript = { "/usr/bin/julia", "/home/thomas/Julia/script1.jl" };
    String[] serverScript = { "/usr/bin/julia", "/home/thomas/Julia/script2.jl" };

    Process server = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(serverScript);
    Process client = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(clientScript);
```

and instantiate two threads to read their outputs:

```
    (new ProcessReader(server)).start();
    (new ProcessReader(client)).start();
```

using

```
public class ProcessReader extends Thread {
    private Process p;

    public ProcessReader(Process p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Read: " + line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Although, since the `clientScript` doesn't produce any output, you could just
start the scripts, and only read the output from the server script - no thread needed.

There's one more thing to consider: the `serverScript` must be `listening...` before the `clientScript` attempts to connect. So you may want to do this:

```
    Process server = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(serverScript);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
    if ( in.readLine().equals("listening...") ) {
        Process client = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(clientScript);

        String line;
        while ( (line=in.readLine()) != null )
            System.out.println("Read: " + line );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw, ZMQ can hold the message sent with its own thread even if the receiver hasn't been there. In this case, we can't close the context of ZMQ but we don't need to make sure that the server must be executed before the execution of the client.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a specific answer to your question, this may help to you or other users that attempt to similar jobs.

JuliaCaller is an early stage library for calling Julia from Java. It executes the Julia executable as a Java process and runs a script in the Julia side. This script opens a TCP server that listens on a given port number. Every command, statement or expression sent from Java is then executed and results are sent back to Java in JSON format.

This library also implements the standard javax.script interface, that means, Julia libraries, functions, and programs can run like a scripting language that is implemented in Java (mimics).

Here is the example:

```
Constants.setProperties(Constants.JULIA_PATH, "/usr/local/bin/julia");
Constants.setProperties(Constants.JULIA_PORT, "8001");

// Creating a scripting interface for Julia
manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
engine = manager.getEngineByName("Julia");

// Sending command 'a = 3' to Julia from Java
engine.eval("a = 3");

// Handling the result in Java
Object a = engine.get("a");
```

More examples are given in the GitHub page.

[Source code with Apache License](https://github.com/jbytecode/juliacaller)